# ImportError: cannot import name rewriter_config_pb2

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am simply following the tutorials of tensorflow and while performing following cmd :

```
python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=/home/priyankit/data/validsrc2-hi --
model=small
```

It is showing following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 68, in 
import util
File "/home/priyankit/models-master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/util.py", line 
23, in 
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name rewriter_config_pb2
```

[link to the repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb)

Comment: upgrade your tensorflow version. `pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.2.0`

Comment: yes I did . This issue got resolved Thanks! But now its showing the following error:
ValueError: Your machine has only 0 gpus which is less than the requested --num_gpus=1.     You can check ptb_word_lm.py in above mentioned link , that is where the error is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things. First, upgrade tensorflow by doing:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Second, if you are not using a GPU, then execute the script with 0 GPUs as follows:

```
python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=/home/priyankit/data/validsrc2-hi --model=small --num_gpus=0
```

Answer (score -2):

I had exactly the same error loop when I tried doing the RNN Tensorflow tutorial on their website.

What worked for me (I don't have a GPU) was including this at the end "--num_gpus=0" when running my program on the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! I don't think OP's problem has anything to do with the specified option. Are you 100% sure that's what removed the error ? If you meant to reply to the question in the comment, then, consider saying this, i.e. "regarding your other question (in the comment)... "